# Error in apply(cos2, 1, sum, na.rm = TRUE) : dim(X) must have a positive length when using in Mixed Factor Analysis

Tags: r, pca, factor-analysis

I am doing a FAMD Analysis getting an error when using the function `fviz_famd_var()`. I am trying to plot the correlation between variables following steps on this tutorial: [link](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/115-famd-factor-analysis-of-mixed-data-in-r-essentials/)

I am stuck on the step `Quantitative variables` because of the error. The above lines are correct. Here is the code:

```
data_famd <- FAMD(data, graph = FALSE)

var <- get_famd_var(data_famd)
# Plot of variables
fviz_famd_var(data_famd, repel = TRUE)
# Contribution to the first dimension
fviz_contrib(data_famd, "var", axes = 1)
# Contribution to the second dimension
fviz_contrib(data_famd, "var", axes = 2)
# quantitative
quanti.var <- get_famd_var(data_famd, "quanti.var")
# correlation between vars
fviz_famd_var(data_famd, "quanti.var", repel = TRUE, col.var = "black")
```

Where data is an array with 30 rows and 5 columns